# Asynchronous parallelization of LLM calls

Tags: parallelization, scheduledtask, llm

The [new LLM functionality in Mathematica 13.3](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/06/llm-tech-and-a-lot-more-version-13-3-of-wolfram-language-and-mathematica/) is really quite slick.  But it is often the case that [one wants to apply it to many items in parallel, i.e., to submit many jobs simultaneously](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289376/63709).  The [OpenAI rate limits are quite generous, allowing for thousands of simultaneous jobs per minute.](https://platform.openai.com/account/rate-limits) **How do you submit many jobs asynchronously to this API**?

As a concrete example, a pattern in text summarization is to divide a large document into chunks that fit into the context window and generate summaries of each chunk.  For example:

```mathematica
exampleData = With[
   {url ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thamsuppp/llm_summary_medium/\
master/stateoftheunion.txt"},
   Partition[#, UpTo[10], 8] &@DeleteCases[""]@Import[url, "List"]];

Length[%]
```

Doing this serially with `Map` is slow:

```mathematica
AbsoluteTiming[
  summaries1 = LLMResourceFunction["Summarize"] /@ exampleData; ]

(*{131.585, Null}*)
```

Doing this will `ParallelMap` is limited by the number of processors/tasks in Mathematica:

```mathematica
$ProcessorCount
AbsoluteTiming[
  summaries2 = ParallelMap[ LLMResourceFunction["Summarize"], exampleData];]

(*4*)

(*{31.609, Null}*)
```

I suspect [SessionSubmit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SessionSubmit.html) might be able to do something like this, but I cannot quite parse how to make this work.  Or maybe there is some special built-in magic for parallelizing requests in the LLM functionality? Or maybe just use the [OpenAI Service Connection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/OpenAI.html) directly?

Comment: According to the [OpenAI Service Connection documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/OpenAI.html) some request types (specifically `"Embedding"`) can operate on lists.  Others, like `"Completion"` only operate only single strings; it may be possible to parallelize this using the `"Chat"` request type ...